# Static container height combined with a dynamically sized container, possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to have two `<div>` containers, one having a static height, and a second underneath dynamic, basically just takes up the remaining portion of the viewport?

Inside the the dynamic container, if there is overflow within, the container itself would show scrollbars accordingly. That way the viewport should ever need a y-axis scrollbar.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/kKgQb/1/)

Any ideas? Would it require a lot of scripting or could it be done purely with css?

Comment: For the div container scrollbars, you can set `overflow:auto;` in CSS which will display scrollbars only if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/X5rWb/

**CSS:**

```
.content{
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow-y: auto; /* now scrollbars will only appear when needed */
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    adjustHeight();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
   adjustHeight();
});

function adjustHeight() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height() - 2;
    var headerHeight = $('.header').outerHeight();

    $('.content').height(windowHeight - headerHeight);
}
```

The 2 in `windowHeight` comes from adding the 1px top and 1px bottom border of the `.content` div together.

Using `outerHeight()` for the `.header` means there is no need to make any additions as the top and bottom padding and borders are included. If you were to use `outerHeight(true)` this would also include the top and bottom margin.

Comment: I downvoted because it's not a good way to solve representation issues via Javascript, especially with jQuery.

Comment: @sedictor: You will notice there is a jQuery tag in the question as well as a css tag. It is still a good quality answer that works well and can be applicable in other situations. It should not be downvoted just because it was not a pure css solution.

Comment: it's only my thought ;) Sorry, I didn't mention jQuery. Also it's not good to litter in global context with function definition. And users may see jump of markup after DOM loading, it's not good too. But of course, if representation issues can't be solved with pure html+css, you may use js.

Comment: I don't think this deserves a down-vote, but I understand the argument. I wanted to compare the solutions and see what makes most sense.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/kKgQb/29/

```
.content{
    position:absolute;
    top: 212px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    height: auto;

    outline: 1px solid red;   
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header{
    height:200px;
    outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: This produces scrollbars for the viewport and the container.

Comment: +1 for the pure css solution. Though I am not sure how flexible this is.

Comment: @tw16, thanks. It may require some fixing of left/right/top/bottom according to borders/margins/paddings, but it's only way on pure css to set 100% height. And its much more better than javascript despite of this only problem

Comment: I like this, but change the `outline` to `border`, so it works on older browsers...

Answer (score 0):

if your header is static, you could set the height of the container via javascript

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();

$('.content').height(windowHeight - $('.header').height())
```

This doesn't account for padding or margins, but it should give you an idea. You might also want to run this anytime the browser gets resized.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   doResize();
});

function doResize(){
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    $('.content').height(windowHeight - $('.header').height())
}
```

Comment: You should use `outerHeight` for that which includes the border and padding: `$('.content').height(windowHeight - $('.header').outerHeight());`