# Iframe to fill out the window size

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, size

How can have the iframe to automatically takeup the whole space.

http://speedywap.com/ihome/?url=http://dell.com/ for example has the iframe only open upto half the window in mozilla firefox and ie6

How can I make sure that takes the maximum size of the screen. Is there a css or js to do this?

Comment: by making sure html and body have a full width also? html,body,frame{width:100%}

Comment: i have triend that but it doesn't do it for me.

Comment: U see how in ebay they load an iframe and that expands as it loads. thats what i want to do.

Comment: This code works for me, but I have double scroll bar. http://pastebin.com/3GNfV4We

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

**Option 1:**

Since you are trying to use `z-index` you can just add `position:absolute` to `.sourceView`.

```
body {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: hidden; /* add this to stop any double scrollbars */
}

.sourceView {
    height: 93%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute; /* add this */
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
body {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: hidden; /* add this to stop any double scrollbars */
}
```

**Option 3:**

I have a javascript/jQuery solution over here:
[Static container height combined with a dynamically sized container, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072153/static-container-height-combined-with-a-dynamically-sized-container-possible/7072430#7072430)

http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/X5rWb/